# delete from a local json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Newbie angular question but im trying to figure out how to delete elements from a local json file

I'm reading them back correctly and have them displayed on my page. 
I have a Remove button with ng-click calling the removeRow function below which removes an item from the scope (thus removing them from the screen).
I want to permanently remove them from the json file though...

I was looking at http.delete but couldnt find any good examples of what i needed... is this the correct function to use?..

just to add im using a node js http server without any rest endpoints configured. It this a must to use delete, post etc?

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.tables = {};

    $http.get('test.json').success(function (data){
      $scope.tables = data;
    });

   $scope.removeRow = function(idx) {

      $scope.tables.splice(idx, 1); 

   }


}]);
```

Comment: good question, me also facing the same issue and I could not find answer. Did you find and solution? if yes, then could you write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes a server is a must to create/delete/manipulate a file. You can make a `$http` call(delete) to your nodeJS server, which in turn should do what you want using ***[fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)*** module.

I would suggest, pass the `key-value` pairs to your server using the `$http` call and use *fs* to make changes to the corrosponding file.

Comment: You actually don't provide any concrete solution. Would an `$http` call automagically remove an item from the file? And how would that call look like?

Comment: @zeroflagL. I guess I have provided enough info to start. The OP have not asked the complete procedure to do it.

Comment: hey, thanks for clearing that up, i will look into it... im assuming i need to have express installed with it exposing the endpoints.. sound right?

Comment: @blu10 Express is not mandatory, but I would suggest use it as its a framework for nodeJS which makes life easy to handle routing, which is you case(such as angular on client-side javascript).